# Checking quality assurance of MOD10A1 NDSI for snow fraction retrieval

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, data-quality

I have recently retrieved some snow fraction data over Fennoscandia from GEE for the first time. I realise the script has no quality assurance that is a built-in feature in MODIS imagery normally.
Here is the script I used:

```
var startDoy = 1;

var startYear = 2000;
var endYear = 2021;

var startDate;
var startYear;

function addDateBands(img) {
  // Get image date.
  var date = img.date();
  // Get calendar day-of-year.
  var calDoy = date.getRelative('day', 'year');
  // Get relative day-of-year; enumerate from user-defined startDoy.
  var relDoy = date.difference(startDate, 'day');
  // Get the date as milliseconds from Unix epoch.
  var millis = date.millis();
  // Add all of the above date info as bands to the snow fraction image.
  var dateBands = ee.Image.constant([calDoy, relDoy, millis, startYear])
    .rename(['calDoy', 'relDoy', 'millis', 'year']);
  // Cast bands to correct data type before returning the image.
  return img.addBands(dateBands)
    .cast({'calDoy': 'int', 'relDoy': 'int', 'millis': 'long','year': 'int'})
    .set('millis', millis);
}

//transform imgage collection into multiband image for export
var stackCollection = function(collection) {
  var first = ee.Image(collection.first()).select([]);
  var appendBands = function(image, previous) {
    return ee.Image(previous).addBands(image);
  };
  return ee.Image(collection.iterate(appendBands, first));
};

var waterMask = ee.Image('MODIS/MOD44W/MOD44W_005_2000_02_24')
  .select('water_mask')
  .not();
  
var completeCol = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD10A1')
  .select('NDSI_Snow_Cover');

// Pixels must have been 10% snow covered for at least 2 weeks in 2018.
var snowCoverEphem = completeCol.filterDate('2018-01-01', '2019-01-01')
  .map(function(img) {
    return img.gte(10);
  })
  .sum()
  .gte(14);
  
// Pixels must not be 10% snow covered more than 124 days in 2018.
var snowCoverConst = completeCol.filterDate('2018-01-01', '2019-01-01')
  .map(function(img) {
    return img.gte(10);
  })
  .sum()
  .lte(124);
  
var analysisMask = waterMask.multiply(snowCoverEphem).multiply(snowCoverConst);

var years = ee.List.sequence(startYear, endYear);

var annualList = years.map(function(year) {
  // Set the global startYear variable as the year being worked on so that
  // it will be accessible to the addDateBands mapped to the collection below.
  startYear = year;
  // Get the first day-of-year for this year as an ee.Date object.
  var firstDoy = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1);
  // Advance from the firstDoy to the user-defined startDay; subtract 1 since
  // firstDoy is already 1. Set the result as the global startDate variable so
  // that it is accessible to the addDateBands mapped to the collection below.
  startDate = firstDoy.advance(startDoy-1, 'day');
  // Get endDate for this year by advancing 1 year from startDate.
  // Need to advance an extra day because end date of filterDate() function
  // is exclusive.
  var endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'year').advance(1, 'day');
  // Filter the complete collection by the start and end dates just defined.
  var yearCol = completeCol.filterDate(startDate, endDate);
  // Construct an image where pixels represent the first day within the date
  // range that the lowest snow fraction is observed.
  var noSnowImg = yearCol
    // Add date bands to all images in this particular collection.
    .map(addDateBands)
    // Sort the images by ascending time to identify the first day without
    // snow. Alternatively, you can use .sort('millis', false) to
    // reverse sort (find first day of snow in the fall).
    .sort('millis')
    // Make a mosaic composed of pixels from images that represent the
    // observation with the minimum percent snow cover (defined by the
    // NDSI_Snow_Cover band); include all associated bands for the selected
    // image.
    .reduce(ee.Reducer.min(5))
    // Rename the bands - band names were altered by previous operation.
    .rename(['snowCover', 'calDoy', 'relDoy', 'millis', 'year'])
    // Apply the mask.
    .updateMask(analysisMask)
    // Set the year as a property for filtering by later.
    .set('year', year);

  // Mask by minimum snow fraction - only include pixels that reach 0
  // percent cover. Return the resulting image.
  return noSnowImg.updateMask(noSnowImg.select('snowCover').eq(0));
});

var annualCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(annualList);
```

I would like to know whether I am detecting the actual snow cover fraction or I am actually retrieving something from a cloud or at night etc. from the table [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_006_MOD10A1#bands)

How can I get the quality assurance for pixels in `MOD10A1` for a given year?